# Select from two temp tables into another temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have created two temp tables and now I have to insert the data from both tables into the third temp table which I will later use in my procedure.

First two temps are populated with the data from regular tables and this is just fine.
But when I try to insert data from those two temps into my final temp table(#3) I receive this:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

Even though I have the same number of items, I receive this Msg.

```
 CREATE TABLE #3
 (
 Vrsta_Reprograma int,
 Datum_Kreiranja smalldatetime NOT NULL,
 Verzija smallint NULL,
 Zakljucano smallint NULL,
 HostName nvarchar(128) NULL,
 Datum_Izvjestaja varchar(10) NULL,
 Aplikacija varchar(10) NULL,
 OJK varchar(12) NULL,
 PartnerID int NULL


 )

 INSERT INTO #3
 (
 Vrsta_Reprograma,
 Datum_Kreiranja,
 Verzija,
 Zakljucano,
 HostName,
 Datum_Izvjestaja,
 Aplikacija,
 OJK,
 PartnerID

 )
 SELECT Vrsta_Reprograma 
   FROM #1

 SELECT (
 Datum_Kreiranja,
 Verzija,
 Zakljucano,
 HostName,
 Datum_Izvjestaja,
 Aplikacija,
 OJK,
 PartnerID,
 )
    FROM #2
```

**Is this the correct approach ?**

Comment: Something seems up in the SQL, you are inserting into #3 a single field  from #1 and then performing an unrelated select on #2. You are not joining #1 to #2 in any form. Did you mean to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though I have the same number of items

No, you don't:

> INSERT INTO #3
>    (
>    Vrsta_Reprograma,
>    Datum_Kreiranja,
>    Verzija,
>    Zakljucano,
>    HostName,
>    Datum_Izvjestaja,
>    Aplikacija,
>    OJK,
>    PartnerID,

= 9 columns (`Vista_Reprograma`, ..., `PartnerID`).

> )
>    SELECT Vrsta_Reprograma 
>      FROM #1

= 1 column (`Vrsta_Reprograma`).

Make sure your SELECT clause the same number of columns as your INSERT INTO clause. What you proably wanted to write was:

```
 INSERT INTO #3
 (
 Vrsta_Reprograma,
 Datum_Kreiranja,
 Verzija,
 Zakljucano,
 HostName,
 Datum_Izvjestaja,
 Aplikacija,
 OJK,
 PartnerID
 )
 SELECT #1.Vrsta_Reprograma, 
        #2.Datum_Kreiranja,
        ...
        #2.PartnerID,
 )
    FROM #1 INNER JOIN #2 ON ...join conditions which matches rows from #1 to those from #2...
```

Comment: I have another one below, 
SELECT (
 Datum_Kreiranja,
 Verzija,
 Zakljucano,
 HostName,
 Datum_Izvjestaja,
 Aplikacija,
 OJK,
 PartnerID,
 )
    FROM #2

Comment: The issue looks more like a logical one - a lack of a join